# Concurrent user access to WCF Service

Tags: wcf, iis-7, threadpool

I have a wcf service using http binding hosted in IIS 7.0 implemented and this service needs to support say 100 concurrent users, so what are the best setting in WCF to achieve this (cpu consumption should be minimal).

Question 2:

I have enabled concurrency mode to "Multiple" and when i mocked 100 concurrent users using a prototype, I don't see 100 threads use by w3p.exe ? does IIS manages how the threads handled in WCF service ? why I am not able to see 100 threads which I have given from client concurrently ?

thanks in advance

Abhinay

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the middle of a big WCF project right now and was tasked with checking performance using the Service Host throttling, one of the behaviors in WCF.

```
System.servicemodel.description.ServiceThrottlingBehavior 
stb.MaxConcurrentSessions = iConcurrentSessions
stb.MaxConcurrentCalls = iConcurrentCalls
stb.MaxConcurrentInstances = iConcurrentInstances
```

It's going to be very difficult for you to create 100 concurrent users using a serial application because the requests are processed so quickly. I ran dozens of tests using a specially-created multi-threaded application that cranked out users and requests in the range of a thousand a second.

I can't answer everything you're asking here, but I'll give you this. I ran dozens of performance tests, first without throttling and then with. The fastest I could get my service to run was without throttling - basically letting the service manager itself. Then I tried various throttling modes setting the concurrent sessions, calls and instances from high values (1000) to low values (10) and, frankly didn't see a big different in speed or resource usage (memory and cpu).

Good luck with the project